# cy.visit() in before(..) block result in CypressError: Cannot call cy.visit() outside a running test

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I am writing spec file for Cypress. I have one spec file including 3-4 tests. each test using the same url so instead of writing cy.visit in each test, I am trying to move in before(..) block.

```
  before(){
    cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/');
  }
```

but I am getting CypressError: Cannot call cy.visit() outside a running test.
How can use cy.visit in before(..) block?

Comment: You are calling the `before()` function without a parameter, which should be a function. Do it like the answer below and it will work

Comment: Thank I missed that

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the arrow function,
try like this

```
        before(() => {
            cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/');
        });
```

cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)